# owner only view function

Tags: solidity

Is it possible to make a function only callable by owner but restricted to view?
I tried something like that.

```
function getUserTokenBalance(address user) public view onlyAdmin returns (uint256) {
    return balance[user];
}
```

Calling this method from `web3` like:

```
contract.methods
 .getUserTokenBalance('0x06bf3b021f10712655a8786f2bFfF11ddE0ea21B')
 .call({ from: account.address })
 .then((data) => {
   console.log('balance: ', data);
 })
.catch((err) => {
  console.log('error', err);
});
```

returns some weird long number as string `3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331534351508065746944`

I guess it's not working because I have to send a transaction so the smart contract can verify me as the owner. However, what I want to achieve is to query some state in the smart contract without paying any fees.

Comment: Similar questions [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/80921) and [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/80870). To my understanding, this is a bug in either web3.js or the node that you're communicating with. In short, don't use a `require` statement which contains an error-message (and I'm guessing that the `onlyAdmin` modifier contains such `require` statement) in a `view` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since everything is public on the blockchain when you deploy a smart contract, you cannot make a field that's hidden from everyone except the owner unfortunately. For more info on this, check out this [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/make-data-from-smartcontracts-events-only-visible-for-certain-address-users?rq=1). The closest you can get is by limiting some functionality to the owner, like this for example:

```
  // Owner address of the contract
  address public owner;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

   // A owner-only callable function
   function onlyOwner () public{
     require(msg.sender == owner, "This can only be called by the contract owner!");
     // Do stuff
   }
```

Comment: thanks. I already have something like that ` modifier onlyAdmin() {
    require(msg.sender == owner, 'Only owner can call this function.');
    _;
  }`. sounds legit. why would you prevent someone from seeing something if it should be public available

Comment: @jetblack 1. Private functions reduce the contract size. 2. Private data cannot be read by other smart contracts.